# Why did Godzilla cause a Tsunami in Hawaii?

Tags: godzilla-2014, monsterverse

### Why a Tsunami at Hawaii?

We see a huge Tusnami in Hawaii as Godzilla approches,

As we are all aware, it takes huge amounts of energy to create a tsunami so how did Godzilla manage to create a tsunami that big?

Comment: is godzilla big enough to make a tsunami, id think maybe some large localized waves at most given his size

Comment: @Himarm, I was going to ask that. But per this site, that would be speculation. Rolleyes.

Comment: It takes massive displacements, underwater, to create a tsunami.  Thousands or millions of times the mass of one giant radioactive lizard. Maybe the question shouldn't be why didn't he create on in SF, but why did he appear to make one in Hawaii.

Comment: Because tsunamis are cinematically exciting.

Comment: I thought this was about motivation, rather than how Godzilla managed to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming we take the [film's novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18594685-godzilla---the-official-movie-novelization) as an explanation, it would seem that when Godzilla arrived in Hawaii, he went for a bit of a splish-splash near the beach. The "*tsunami*" was evidently the result of him kicking up spray.

> Caught up in their celebratory meal, the couple completely failed to
>   notice as, less than a mile away, a huge reptilian beast rose up from
>   the bay to tower over Waikiki. Torrents of cascading seawater veiled
>   the monster’s form so that only the titanic proportions of the
>   leviathan were revealed. Standing erect on two stout legs, the monster
>   was nearly four hundred feet tall and solidly built, with a broad
>   chest and brawny forearms. A pair of enormous jaws, resembling those
>   of some prehistoric saurian, opened wide, but the creature’s roar was
>   drowned out by the urgent wail of a tsunami warning.

By comparison, when he arrived in San Francisco he came out of the water relatively sedately (having been slowed up by the Golden Gate Bridge) and then stepped straight out onto land.

> Godzilla rose from the bay and stepped onto the land. His thunderous
>   tread shook the earth as he stomped through industrial shipyards and
>   piers. Office buildings and warehouses were reduced to splinters
>   beneath him. A cable car was crushed beneath a great, clawed foot. His
>   tail whipped behind him, toppling entire buildings.

And yes, I'm aware that this makes no sense. Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: I will up vote that. Thanks.

Comment: A HUGE lizard must produce HUGE waves = tsunami. The reasoning makes perfect sense, yeah.

Comment: @Oriol - Water effects are nice and cheap to show. The tech is extremely well established, to the point that you can simulate a fairly large flood live; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5XBfqc3rXs&feature=youtu.be&t=127

Comment: That sounds like an appallingly bad novelisation!  “Solidly built” 